# Elbow method using hclus.scree, error could not find function

Tags: r, r-daisy

I have found several documents that use function "hclus.scree" to use the elbow method to identify number of clusters. However, R cannot find the hclus.scree function. Is this a version of R thing? I have tried multiple libraries, but maybe I am still missing the key one.

> library(cluster)
>   DissimDaisy <- daisy(TraitData, metric = "gower")
>   AveClust <- hclust(DissimDaisy, method = "average", members = NULL)
>   hclus.scree(AveClust)
>   Error: could not find function "hclus.scree"